# Ignore field on mapping and indexing using ElasticSearch and java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm developing an application using ElasticSearch, I want  to index a document but ignoring some field.

```
@Document(indexName = "my_index", type = "user")
public class User{

    @Id
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private Adress adresse; //ignored field 

    getters and setters

}
```

Thanks in advance